# NoSuchMethodError in lxg.a

Tags: nosuchmethoderror

My users are getting this crash from my app, but I haven't a clue where it is coming from.  It is mostly coming from Gingerbread users.  The bug report from the Developer Console looks like this:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.ViewParent.requestSendAccessibilityEvent
at lxg.a(Unknown Source)
at lxx.a(Unknown Source)
at kzf.c(Unknown Source)
at lnx.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The app is here:

https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C5CHFA_enCA507CA507&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=trailnav

The app uses in app purchases and the camera.  Could it be coming from one of those packages?

Comment: Yes, it could be coming from one of those packages, from somewhere in your own code, or from some totally different package. Based on the information you've provided here, there's no information we can use to try and help; the link to your app is irrelevant. (IOW, your question is far too vague and lacking in detail to be answered.)

Comment: Ken, I'm sure you're an excellent fellow, but if you don't have anything useful to add to the conversation, could you please refrain from commenting.  As I patiently explained in my post, my users are experiencing a crash, and this is all the information I have.  My own testing has revealed no problems with my app.  The link to my app is very relevant for persons who actually know something about Android development.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? My error seems to be coming from google maps on older android devices. I am getting the exact same error, no code obfuscation.

Answer (score 1):

[android.view.ViewParent.requestSendAccessibilityEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewParent.html#requestSendAccessibilityEvent(android.view.View,%20android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent)) was added in API 14 (Android 4.0). This crash appears when you try to call the method on a device with a lower API level.

The following code:

> at lxg.a(Unknown Source)
>   at lxx.a(Unknown Source)
>   at kzf.c(Unknown Source)

Looks like an obfuscated code. So you're either using Proguard to obfuscate your code or you're using an external library which was obfuscated.

If you obfuscated the code with Proguard, then you can decode the obfuscated code as explained [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding). If you are using some external obfuscated library, then you can either search their documentation to see if they support API levels lower than 14. If they do, then you can send them a bug report.